# Scaling pyplot in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to scale a contour plot on top of a scatter plot in matplotlib. I have two datasets called dataset1 and dataset2 in the format of [[list],[list], ...] and x1, y1 respectively.

I can produce the contours by;
    CS = plt.contour(dataset1[:,:])
However this produces an x,y coordinates between 0 to the length of dataset1.

This poses a bit of a problem since the plot needs to be in real world coordinates just like dataset2. Is there a way to scale the x and y axis to the appropriate position i.e y+3290000 and x+750000 ? Whilst keeping the contours in the same place and allowing for the scatter diagram to be shown?

Comment: You should post the code you are using to get the plot you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

You should really read the documentation.

http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.imshow

That way you can discover an option of extent which gives you (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)

Comment: Yes because it was a stupid question, and got the answer after reading the documentation a third time over.  :P

Comment: Answering your own question is a good thing. This is a link-only answer, though. Please write a proper solution.